# Trouble With Upper Tube Race Installation

Tags: headset

I was able to install the lower race without issue, but I cannot seem to get the upper one installed.  I am installing a new threaded headset on a newly painted bike.  There is no new paint blocking the surface.  I do not have any professional tools for this installation, just a hammer and a block of wood.

Is there any trick to getting it in there or do I need to have my LBS ream it out?

Comment: Describe specifically what problem are you having: is the upper race entering sideways or twisted? is it going partially and then blocking? Is it not entering at all?

Comment: It is entering then blocking, once blocked it will start to go sideways if pushed further.

Comment: **UPDATE** I was able to get the race in, it required using a Dremel tool on the head to smooth it out a little, than used the home made press.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use the "recommended" way to do that (even if that means using a home-made solution:

1. Find two plates (wood, metal) which you can drill a hole through;
2. Put each one of these (already drilled) plates on each end of the head tube, with the cups already positioned for insertion;
3. Insert a long bolt or threaded rod through it all;
4. Insert two nuts on each end, and press the system together, so that the cups are forced inside the frame in the proper position.

If you have a <strike>wise bench</strike> bench vise, you can do the same, but I would recommend using the plates too (not the raw jaws of the vise).

Comment: Great suggestion, should I remove the lower cup and reinstall this way?

Comment: No, it is not needed to remove the lower cup. Good luck (and don't forget to accept the answer if you feel like it :o)

Comment: It's possible that there is damage to the cup from your original attempt to install it. I hope not, but check it before ou try again.

Comment: Great idea, unfortunately, the race is just too big, I am going to have to figure out something else.